# how to test expressJS controller- NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sinon, chai

Trying to unit test my controller, but when I do so I'm getting the following error.

**I'm open to answers with a different way of testing my controller.**

**Error:**

> TypeError: expected sinon object

```
 const test = require('sinon-test');



 describe('index (get all)', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      res = {
        json: sinon.spy(),
        status: sinon.stub().returns({ end: sinon.spy() })
      };
      expectedResult = [{}, {}, {}];
    });
    it(
      'should return array of vehicles or empty array',
      test(() => {
        this.stub(Vehicle, 'find').yields(null, expectedResult);
        Controller.index(req, res);
        sinon.assert.calledWith(Vehicle.find, {});
        sinon.assert.calledWith(res.json, sinon.match.array);
      })
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when asking a StackOverflow question, it makes sense to post a fully runnable example and stating all dependencies. Basically, I used more than an hour trying to test this out because both were missing.

This is the fully expanded example, just with dummy implementations of your two main objects.

```
var sinon = require("sinon");
var sinonTest = require("sinon-test");
var test = sinonTest(sinon);

const Vehicle = {
  find() {}
};
const Controller = {
  index() {}
};

describe("index (get all)", function() {
  let expectedResult, res, req;

  beforeEach(function() {
    res = {
      json: sinon.spy(),
      status: sinon.stub().returns({ end: sinon.spy() })
    };
    expectedResult = [{}, {}, {}];
  });

  it(
    "should return array of vehicles or empty array",
    test(function() {
      this.stub(Vehicle, "find").yields(null, expectedResult);
      Controller.index(req, res);
      sinon.assert.calledWith(Vehicle.find, {});
      sinon.assert.calledWith(res.json, sinon.match.array);
    })
  );
});
```

Now, to your question, which was why you were getting an error. The first thing to test is: does the bug appear when I update to the latest versions of the dependencies of the test? The answer is, *no, it does not appear*. So basically, this is about you using the `sinon-test` version 2.0, which had a compatibility bug with Sinon 3. This is from the [changelog](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon-test/blob/master/History.md):

```
2.1.0 / 2017-08-07
==================
Fix compatibility with Sinon 3 (#77)


2.0.0 / 2017-06-22
==================

  * Simplify configuration API (#74)
```

So, given that has been fixed, and the example below is being used, the test is fully runnable:

```
mocha mytest.js 


  index (get all)
    1) should return array of vehicles or empty array


  0 passing (6ms)
  1 failing

  1) index (get all)
       should return array of vehicles or empty array:
     AssertError: expected find to be called with arguments
```

The error here is of course not really an error, but simply a byproduct of me not having the full implementation of your controller and vehicle classes.